# mayavi2 does not work

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi2, mayavi

I install mayavi2 using sudo apt-get install mayavi2 as shown below:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install mayavi2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
python-enthoughtbase
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
python-envisage
Suggested packages:
ipython python-chaco
The following packages will be REMOVED:
python-envisagecore python-envisageplugins
The following NEW packages will be installed:
mayavi2 python-envisage
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 2 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/18.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 34.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 160193 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-envisagecore (3.2.0-2) ...
Removing python-envisageplugins (3.2.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-envisage.
(Reading database ... 158978 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-envisage_4.4.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-envisage (4.4.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mayavi2.
Preparing to unpack .../mayavi2_4.3.1-3.1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking mayavi2 (4.3.1-3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up python-envisage (4.4.0-1) ...
Setting up mayavi2 (4.3.1-3.1) ...
Now

I try to run mayavi2 but there is error as shown below.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mayavi2

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/mayavi2", line 493, in 
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: No module named _py2to3

Could not load envisage. You might have a missing dependency.
Do you have the EnvisageCore and EnvisagePlugins installed?

If you installed Mayavi with easy_install, try 'easy_install '.
'easy_install Mayavi[app]' will also work.

If you performed a source checkout and installed via 'python setup.py develop',
be sure to run the same command in the EnvisageCore and EnvisagePlugins folders.

If these packages appear to be installed, check that your numpy and
configobj are installed and working. If you need numpy, 'easy_install numpy'
will install numpy. Similarly, 'easy_install configobj' will install
configobj.

I install envisage, EnvisageCore, and EnvisagePulgins using
sudo apt-get install python-envisage
sudo apt-get install python-EnvisageCore
sudo apt-get install python-EnvisagePlugins

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mayavi2
bash: /usr/bin/mayavi2: No such file or directory

Hi is there a way to get past this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as your `mayavi2` executable has been removed (this is typically the case with the message `bash: /usr/bin/mayavi2: No such file or directory`), it likely means that apt-get removed it when updating python-envisage, python-EnvisageCore and python-EnvisagePlugins.

First steps: `apt-get update`, `apt-get install mayavi2` (both as root or using sudo) and check if the errors are the same. The first error you had was about a missing `_py2to3` module that normally comes with the packages `python-traits` and `python-traitsui. Are they installed?

Comment: I already installed  python-traits and `python-traitsui as shown below.

pi@raspberrypi $ sudo apt-get install python-traits

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree     
   
Reading state information... Done

python-traits is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi $ sudo apt-get install python-traitsui

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree  
     
Reading state information... Done

python-traitsui is already the newest version.

python-traitsui set to manually installed.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.

Comment: I did apt-get update and upgrade and then I reinstall mayavi2. I got the same message as shown in my problem. The following packages will be REMOVED: python-envisagecore python-envisageplugins

Comment: Is it possible that you have installed other packages (with pip for instance) that would be located in `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`?